# How I can tell alias of the wanted key-entry to SSLSocket before connecting?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, authentication

I have two certificate/key pairs in a Java keystore. Aliases of those key-entries are "foo" and "bar".

My TLS client (Java program) uses the keystore. TLS client authentication is done during connection opening.
The client program should use "foo" key-entry when TLS server request certificate from the client.
Now the client send wrong certificate ("bar") to the server during connection handshake.

How I can tell alias of the wanted key-entry to `SSLSocket` before connecting?

Currently the code is following:

```
final SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(); 
ss.setEnabledProtocols( new String[] {"TLSv1"});
ss.connect( targetAddress );
```

Comment: What's the 'bar' entry for? Why do you have two client certificates?

Comment: @EJP : The client program is a testing program. Several key-entries are needed for testing different kind of use cases.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The default `KeyManager` will send the first certificate it finds that matches the conditions requested by the server, that is, it will send the first one it find for which it can build a certification chain up one of the CA names sent by the server during the request.

If you always want a specific alias to be chosen, you'll need to implement your own [`X509KeyManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509KeyManager.html), possibly wrapping the default manager. Something along these lines should work (not tested this actual code, there may be a few typos):

```
KeyStore keystore = ... // create and load your keystore.

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keystore, password.toCharArray());

final X509KeyManager origKm = (X509KeyManager)kmf.getKeyManagers()[0];

X509KeyManager km = new X509KeyManager() {
    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        return "foo";
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
        return origKm.getCertificateChain(alias);
    }

    // Delegate the rest of the methods from origKm too...
}
```

Then use it for your `SSLContext`:

```
SSLContext sslContext = sslContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(new KeyManager[] { km }, null, null);
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
```

Comment: This looks like promising. I will try this today.

Comment: @User1: Can you please post the complete code to implement this?