# Dynamic SSL Keystore/Certificate selection

Tags: java, ssl, spring-boot, certificate, soap-client

My application is a web service provider running on websphere and a SOAP web service client consists of several keystores specific to each client. The app needs to be migrated to tomcat and i am struck, as i need to use a different certs to establish the TLS connection with back end server based on the incoming client request

I am using springboot and have a way to configure keystore and trustore. Followed the below link:

http://zoltanaltfatter.com/2016/04/30/soap-over-https-with-client-certificate-authentication/

I want to set the certificate/keystore at run time based on the client. To do that I am wiring Keystores and the configuration(client) names, so that I can use the client specific keystore dynamically. But this is something tightly coupled, each time i have a new client, I need to create an entry for the client and set the corresponding keystore.

But I had some another approach in mind, say I keep all certificates in one keystore , how we can access the client specific cert dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a keystore to manage all your client certificates, that will be identified by an alias.

The default `KeyManager` will select the first certificate in handshake, so before  creating the connection no need to build your own `X509KeyManager` to specify the alias to be used. See [How I can tell alias of the wanted key-entry to SSLSocket before connecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201251/how-i-can-tell-alias-of-the-wanted-key-entry-to-sslsocket-before-connecting)

```
KeyStore keystore = ... //The keystore with all your certificates

//The keymanager for an specific connection
KeyManagerFactory kmf=  KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keystore, password.toCharArray());

//Create a keyManager wrapper that returns the alias to use
final X509KeyManager origKm = (X509KeyManager)kmf.getKeyManagers()[0];
X509KeyManager km = new X509KeyManager() {
   public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
       return "alias";
   }

   public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
       return origKm.getCertificateChain(alias);
   }

// override the rest of the methods delegating to origKm ...
}
```

Inject the new `keyManager` in `HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender`

```
HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
//messageSender.setKeyManagers(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers());
messageSender.setKeyManagers(new KeyManager[] { km });
```

Comment: I tried your approach, it worked, but I faced another issue. I declared the X509Keymanager and overrided the above two methods, but when i made a call to the destination server i got the below error message `main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, unexpected_message
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal ` I fixed this error by providing the KeyManager object to the HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender instead of X509KeyManager. The server SSL trace shows that server is not getting the _CERTIFICATE-VERIFY message_ from the client hence the connection is terminated abruptly.

Comment: The exact error is: `Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
 at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561) ~[spring-ws-core- 2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE] .....Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_71]`

Comment: I fixed the issue, looks like my app fetching the private key as null as i didn't override the method. This is the fix: `@Override
   public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return origKm.getPrivateKey(arg0);
   }`

Comment: Could you edit the answer to add the fix of your first comment? It is not clear for mi what to change. Consider also to mark the answer as accepted