# Java Keystore - programatically select the certificate to use from keystore file

Tags: java, ssl

I have a java keystore file which contains multiple client certificates.  I wish to select just one of these certificates in my Java application to connect to a service.  Is there a simple way to do this?  The only way I've found a solution to this so far is to create a new KeyStore in the program using the client cert details (found by its alias) from the original keystore file.  I though there might be a simple way to just say "use the cert from the keystore.jks file with this alias", rather than have to create a new keystore just for the cert you want to use.  Code is as follows:

```
        // Set up Client Cert settings
        KeyStore clientCertStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        clientCertStore.load(new FileInputStream(clientKeystoreLocation), clientKeystorePassword);            

        // Create temporary one keystore, then extract the client cert using it's alias from keystore.jks, then create
        // a new keystore with this cert, that the process will use to connect with.
        KeyStore tempKstore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        tempKstore.load(null);
        tempKstore.setKeyEntry(certificateAlias, clientCertStore.getKey(certificateAlias, bwConfig.clientKeystorePassword),
                clientKeystorePassword, clientCertStore.getCertificateChain(certificateAlias));
        clientCertStore = tempKstore;

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(clientCertStore, clientKeystorePassword);            

        // Set up Truststore settings
        File truststoreFile = new File(TrustStoreLocation);
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststoreFile), TrustStorePassword);
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        // Set to TLS 1.2 encryption
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

        SSLSocketFactory ssf = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        ssf.createSocket(serviceURL.getHost(), servicePort);

        bp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", ssf);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question is similar to  [How I can tell alias of the wanted key-entry to SSLSocket before connecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201251/how-i-can-tell-alias-of-the-wanted-key-entry-to-sslsocket-before-connecting)

The default `KeyManager` will select the first certificate in handshake (according to CA list sent by server), You can build your own `X509KeyManager` to specify the alias to be used wrapping the default.

```
final X509KeyManager origKm = (X509KeyManager)keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers()[0];
X509KeyManager km = new X509KeyManager() {
   public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
       return "alias";
   }

   public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
       return origKm.getCertificateChain(alias);
   }

// override the rest of the methods delegating to origKm ...
}
```

Set the new `keyManager` in `SSLContext`

```
 sslContext.init(new KeyManager[] { km }, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

Comment: In both cases I am a little confused by "// override the rest of the methods delegating to origKm ..." Does this just mean take the default suggestion? Like should serverAlias be null?

Comment: NM this helped

https://github.com/zowe/api-layer/blob/adfadffc5310962170bc21c51b04f113973e02a0/certificate-analyser/src/main/java/org/zowe/apiml/SSLContextFactory.java#L51