# handshake_failure and UNKNOWN_CA after importing second .p12 to keystore

Tags: java, soap, ssl-certificate, soapui, keytool

I added a .p12 cert to a keystore (where no cert was in so far) with

```
keytool -importkeystore -noprompt -v -srckeystore FIRSTCert.p12  -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass mySrcPassword -destkeystore keyStore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass myDestPassword -destkeypass myDestPassword
```

I used the keyStore.p12 in SOAP UI with the Password myDestPassword and everthing worked

NOW I imported a second .p12 in my existing KeyStore with ( same parameters):

```
 keytool -importkeystore -noprompt -v -srckeystore SECONDCert.p12  -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass 12345 -destkeystore keyStore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass myDestPassword -destkeypass myDestPassword
```

The import worked, but after I tried to make a SOAP call with the updated keyStore.p12 ( same wsdl and adress like before) I got

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Does anybody know why?

**UPDATE:**

I also tried to use this Key Store in a Java Application. The Behavior is the same. I add the first certificate --> it works. I add the second certificate I get an Error but now, my Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception:  myService.uploadParameters call FAILED with: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP-Transportfehler: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
```

**UPDATE2**
Here as the content of my keystore

```
C:\>keytool -list -keystore KeyStore.p12 -storetype PKCS12
Keystore-Kennwort eingeben:

Keystore-Typ: PKCS12
Keystore-Provider: SunJSSE

Keystore enthält 2 Einträge

muster max (btt/beat2), 23.03.2020, PrivateKeyEntry,
Zertifikat-Fingerprint (SHA1): 03:A0:3C:0F:4A:91:1A:40:2D:C3:EC:A0:23:D5:E6:44:C5:29:34:DC
client_cert_muster, 23.03.2020, PrivateKeyEntry,
Zertifikat-Fingerprint (SHA1): 06:13:A2:8A:84:E8:F9:74:50:E8:BA:D3:79:9F:FB:5F:CB:09:1E:D0
```

Comment: Did you specify separate aliases when you imported the keystores? Default alias is `mykey` and it is likely that the second import overwrote the first one. Normally, `keytool` will warn you about this and ask if you want to proceed, but you specified `-noprompt` so it probably just went ahead did what you told it to.

Comment: The alias are different, I also tried it with no '-noprompt'. Same errror

Comment: Ok, Why do you need to import two complete keypairs? How is the server supposed to know which one of the keys to use? Normally, you would use a keystore with one `PrivateKeyEntry` for the server's identity and the CA's certificate chain as `TrustedCertificateEntry`. Does the same thing happen if you do a `-importkeystore` and then do a `-importcert`?

Comment: I have two .p12 certs, for two server. My app has to connect to both servers. so with `-importcert` my privat key would be missing?

Comment: Wait a minute, is this for the client? Can you do a `keytool -list -keystore keyStore.p12 -storetype pkcs12` and include the output in the question?

Comment: yes. my client uses them. I have no acces to the server. I posted the output

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to put two **keypairs** in the same .p12 and clients normally only need the public part of the keypair, encoded as a X509 certificate. It seems it gets confused about what to do when there is more than `PrivateKeyEntry` entry in the .p12.

In order to get a PKCS12 file with only certificates, try this:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore FIRSTCert.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass mySrcPassword -file firstcert.cer
keytool -exportcert -keystore SECONDCert.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass 12345 -file secondcert.cer
keytool -importcert -keystore keyStore.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass myDestPassword -file firstcert.cer
keytool -importcert -keystore keyStore.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass myDestPassword -file secondcert.cer -alias mykey2
```

Now, when you do a

```
keytool -list -keystore keyStore.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass myDestPassword 


Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

mykey, 23 march 2020, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 26:FB:B4:8F:42:9C:48:5E:EE:8D:35:2E:A5:1C:79:EA:23:B5:36:50:47:62:4D:BC:D1:3D:26:61:04:1C:1A:32
mykey2, 23 march 2020, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): C1:06:CA:06:F1:29:80:72:16:1F:F6:72:04:39:16:17:31:E0:7A:5B:28:BB:41:4C:77:8E:94:F1:C5:8D:70:F8
```

it should have 2 entries and they should be of the type `trustedCertEntry`. This is your *truststore* and it should be the only trust your client needs to make a TLS connection.

Never move the server's complete keypair off the machine unless you really know what you are doing; it should only be known to the server.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think I need a KeyStore on Client Side to authenticate to the Server. I already have an TrustStore. The Common way we did worldwide so far, was to order a .p12 cert,--> authenticate with this p12 cert and download a crt  ( all through the Browser) --> put .crt to TrustStore and .p12 to KeyStore --> make Java Call in App

Comment: Ok, this setup was never mentioned. Just so that I am clear, are you using client-based authentication through TLS in your Java app?

Comment: Yes, the client hast to authenticate  itself on the server  with the .p12 cert with TLS

Answer (score 0):

Thx @Daniel alot for his help.
I finally found a way. I don't know if this is the right one but it works. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42444053/10506010) answer help me.
When I start the application, I init the TLS with only the Truststore:

```
  static void initTLS(String trustStore, String trustStorePW ){
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2")
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",trustStore)
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePW)    
  }
```

And now the new: Befor every (SOAP) call I make a initKeyStore:

```
static void initKeyStore( String aliasName ){
    String keyStorePW = "abc..."
    String keyStorePath = "path/to/keyStore"

    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    char[] pwdArray = keyStorePW.toCharArray();
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStorePath), pwdArray);
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keystore, keyStorePW.toCharArray());

    final X509KeyManager origKm = (X509KeyManager)kmf.getKeyManagers()[0];  
    X509KeyManager km = new X509KeyManager() {

      @Override
      public String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
         return aliasName
      }

      @Override
      public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String alias) {
        return origKm.getCertificateChain(alias);
      }

      @Override
      public String[] getClientAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
        return origKm.getClientAliases(keyType, issuers)
      }

      @Override
      public String[] getServerAliases(String keyType, Principal[] issuers) {
        return origKm.getServerAliases(keyType, issuers)
      }

      @Override
      public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String alias) {
        return origKm.getPrivateKey(alias);
      }

      @Override
      public String chooseServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket) {
        return origKm.chooseServerAlias(keyType, issuers, socket );
      }
    }

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    KeyManager[] kms = [km] 
    sslContext.init(kms, null, null);
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

The Paramter `aliasName` allows me to controll which .p12 cert in the KeyStore will be taken.
I think this is quite dirty and I will have to optimize this code. But finally it works.