# SSL Error : no suitable certificate found continuing without client authentication in java

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-7

I am facing issues with client certificate authentication using java (HttpUrlConnection, HttpClient apache) 
I tried through curl it works :
`curl -v  POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data Jsondata --cert-type P12 --cert path/to/certificat:password https://url -k`

But when i try to execute the some request using java, it gives :
`no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication`

code Java using HttpUrlConnection :

```
                 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
                 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(certificatPath);
                ks.load(fis, password.toCharArray());
                
                KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
                kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
                HttpsURLConnection postConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               if (postConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
                    
                 ((HttpsURLConnection)postConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
               }
```

in ssl logs the keystore and trustore are loaded correctly

```
***
found key for : aliasKey

***
***
trustStore is: javaHome\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
```

but  after "Server done" step, it gives message

```
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication

*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
```

I tested several solutions but I still have the same error message, even if the keystore is loaded with the same private key CN specified in certificate request

```
 *** CertificateRequest
 Cert Types: 
 RSA
 , 
 DSS
,
 ECDSA

Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x1), Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x2), Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x3), SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
CN authorities ....
```

the some code works perfectly with another certificat in some format p12

Comment: Does your keystore have multiple aliases? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201251/how-i-can-tell-alias-of-the-wanted-key-entry-to-sslsocket-before-connecting

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  no, the keystore contain juste one keyEntry

Comment: The only other possibility that I can think of is that you have no certificates that chain to the CAs sent over by the server. Somewhere in the logs the list of DNs of acceptable CAs  sent by the server will be shown.

Comment: thank you @PresidentJamesK.Polk, i have tested the solution proposed in link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201251/how-i-can-tell-alias-of-the-wanted-key-entry-to-sslsocket-before-connecting and it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i tested the solution proposed in link [How I can tell alias of the wanted key-entry to SSLSocket before connecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201251/how-i-can-tell-alias-of-the-wanted-key-entry-to-sslsocket-before-connecting) the problem is resolved :

```
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keystorePath);
                ks.load(fis, keystorePwd.toCharArray());
                
                KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                kmf.init(ks, keystorePwd.toCharArray());

                final X509KeyManager origKm = (X509KeyManager)kmf.getKeyManagers()[0];
                
                X509KeyManager km = new X509KeyManager() {
                    @Override
                    public String[] getClientAliases(String string, Principal[] prncpls) {
                      return  origKm.getClientAliases(string, prncpls);//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] strings, Principal[] prncpls, Socket socket) {
                        return certificatAlias; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String[] getServerAliases(String string, Principal[] prncpls) {
                        return origKm.getServerAliases(string, prncpls); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String chooseServerAlias(String string, Principal[] prncpls, Socket socket) {
                        return origKm.chooseServerAlias(string, prncpls, socket);//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String string) {
                        System.out.println(".getPrivateKey() :"+string) ;
                         return origKm.getPrivateKey(string);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String string) {
                        System.out.println(".etCertificateChain :"+string) ;
                         return origKm.getCertificateChain(string);
                       
                    }
            };
            

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(new KeyManager[] { km }, null, null);
``
```