# HttpClient takes always the first certificate entry form KeyStore

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, keystore, keytool

I have two different keyStores `service1.jks` and `sevice2.jks` for two different services correspondingly (but they have the same RootSertificate though). Here is my `httpClient` which works successfully with the two services:

```
  public HttpClient getHttpClient(String filePath, String password) {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(new File(filePath), password.toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
            .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, password.toCharArray())
            .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, (hostname, session) -> true);

    return HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
            .build();
  }
```

I have a need to use only one shared keyStore in my project. So I merged `service1.jks` and `sevice2.jks` into one common keyStore `common.jks`:

```
cp sevice2.jks common.jks
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore service1.jks -srcstoretype jks -srcstorepass changeit -destkeystore common.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass changeit
```

So `common.jks` has two items:

```
$ keytool -list -storepass changeit -keystore server.keystore.jks
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

service1-alias, 8 сент. 2020 г., PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 
....
service2-alias, 8 сент. 2020 г., PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 
...
```

Then it turned out that my `HttpClient` now works successfully only with the first `service1`, while requests to `service2` became unauthorized. It seems for me that my `HttpClient` takes now only the first entry form `common.jks`. How to make `HttpClient` to use the correct alias for the request?

Comment: More to the point, why do you have two certificates? Two identities? Something wrong here.

Comment: I believe this is the default behaviour. There's a note in the Java docs for SSLContextBuilder: "Please note: the default Oracle JSSE implementation of SSLContext.init(KeyManager[], TrustManager[], SecureRandom) accepts multiple key and trust managers, however only only first matching type is ever used. See for example: SSLContext.html#init"

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne - I have two certificates because I have two different services. So my idea was to have one `httpClient` and one common Keystore.

Comment: @Kevin Boone could you please form this as an answer?

Comment: Your host may have two different services but it doesn't have two different identities. You don't need the certificate to identify the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the default behaviour. There's a [note](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html) in the Javadocs for SSLContextBuilder:

> Please note: the default Oracle JSSE implementation of
> SSLContext.init(KeyManager[], TrustManager[], SecureRandom) accepts
> multiple key and trust managers, however only only first matching type
> is ever used. See for example: SSLContext.html#init

Many Java libraries and frameworks have this problem -- certificates can be stored in a keystore with a alias and, in principle, an application can select which alias to use if it has to present a certificate. However, facilities to do this are often ommited from libraries, on the assumption that an application will never need to use more than a single keystore.

Comment: There is a good way in Java to choose a custom alias from a keystore. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201251/how-i-can-tell-alias-of-the-wanted-key-entry-to-sslsocket-before-connecting and the answer of @Bruno. I am now using this approach for my app and it works.